# Unauthorized Access Exception while trying to write in AppData

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to copy a file from a remote computer in my AppData folder to then access this file whenever i want.
The copy works just fine when the destination path is GetCurrentDir(), but i got an exception every time i try to write elsewhere, in particular AppData.

`pathToCopy = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "imgTemp.jpg");//doesn't work`
`pathToCopy = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "imgTemp.jpg"); //works`

And this is the code for my copy :

```
private void SaveImgTemp(string dest)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Copy(dest, pathToCopy, true);

                if (File.Exists(pathToCopy))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File copied successfully.");
                    
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

If anyone has an answer...

**EDIT:** Apparently, I have no rights to write anything under C:\Users.
I can write everywhere else in C:\ but as soon as I try to go in \Users, bam error thrown.

I don't exactly know why because I can copy whatever I want when I am not using my app.

Anyway, I think I will copy that elsewhere then.

Comment: Maybe Application.ExecutablePath();

Comment: I have indeed no issue writing there, but I want to copy my file in AppData

Comment: What is the value of `dest`? And btw it must be `src`. `GetTempPath()` has to work - there is other reason in your case. What are the error messages?

Comment: `dest` is the path to an image outside my machine. The source is not an issue, I've managed to copy in the directory of the executable. Which is why it is so weird to me that I am not allowed to copy anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply don't have write permissions to the app data folder. If you are debugging, you may need to run Visual Studio as administrator. Alternatively you can give read/write access to the AppData folder to your user.

Comment: Hey, just tried running VS as an administrator, but I have the same error. Also i have the rights concerning AppData, says the security tab of the folder

Comment: Just noticed that you are using ```Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()```. If you are running the app from Visual Studio then this will be the bin folder not AppData. Are you running from VS or installing the app then running?

Comment: Yep sorry my original message was mixed.`Directory.GetDirectory()` works when I run the app from VS, but as soon as I switch to AppData as the destination, I get the error